# Question about the distance between two sets.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am confused about this notation, can someone give me an explicit example on how to calculate the distance between two sets with this formula from real analysis? Also, when would D(A,B)=0?

Let $(\mathcal E,d)$ be a metric space. For non-empty subsets $A,B \subset \mathcal{E}$ define
$$D(A,B):=\max \{\sup_{a\in A} \inf_{\lower{0.5ex}{b \in B}} d(a,b),\sup_{b \in B} \inf_{\lower{0.5ex}{a \in A}} d(a,b)\}.$$
Where, for a map $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$\inf\limits_{s \in S}f(s):=\inf\{f(s):s \in S\}$ and $\sup\limits_{s \in S} f(s) := \sup \{f(s):s\in S\}$

Comment: Which aspect are you having trouble with?

Comment: $D(A,B)$ is the maximum of the upper bound on the lower bound on the distance between two elements in the sets either way.  Which is to say (very informally) the "largest" of the "shortest" distance measures between the sets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. More specifically, could you give me a simple example of how would $sup_{a\in A} \inf_{b \in B} d(a,b) $ and  $\sup_{b \in B} \inf_{a \in A} d(a,b)$ look like on two sets in regular Euclidian $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D(A,B)$ is the maximum of the upper bound on the lower bound on the distance between two elements in the sets either way.   Which is to say (*very* informally) the "largest" of the "shortest" distance measures between the sets.

---

Take, for example $A=\{0, 2\}, B=\{1,2,4\}$ and $d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$

$$\begin{align} {\sup}_{a\in A}{\inf}_{{b\in B}}~d(a,b) = ~ & \sup \big\{\inf \{d(a,b): b\in B\}: a\in A\big\} \\ =~ & \sup\big\{\inf\{d(a,1), d(a, 2), d(a,4)\}: a\in A\big\} \\ = ~ & \sup\big\{\inf \{d(0,1), d(0,2), d(0,4)\},\inf\{d(2,1), d(2,2), d(2,4)\}\big\} \\ = ~ & \sup\big\{\inf\{ 1,2,4\}, \inf\{1,0,2\}\big\} \\=~ & \sup\big\{ 1,0\big\} \\=~ &  1\\[2ex] {\sup}_{b\in B}{\inf}_{{a\in A}}~d(a,b) = ~ & \sup\big\{\inf \{d(a,b): a\in A\}: b\in B\big\} \\ = ~ & \sup\big\{\inf\{d(0,b), d(2,b)\}: b\in B\big\} \\ = ~ & \sup\big\{\inf \{d(0,1), d(2,1)\},\inf\{d(0,2), d(2,2)\},\inf\{d(0,4),d(2,4)\}\big\} \\ = ~ & \sup\big\{\inf\{ 1,1\}, \inf\{2,0\}, \inf\{4,2\}\big\} \\=~ & \sup\big\{ 1,0,2\big\} \\=~ &  2\\[2ex]D(A,B)~=~&\max\{1,2\}\\ =~& 2\end{align}$$

---

$D(A,B)$ will be zero if $\forall a\in A~\exists b\in B: d(a,b)=0$ and $\forall b\in B~\exists a\in A: d(a,b)=0$.   Every point in either set is zero distance from some point in the other set.   (Notice: This is *not* claiming they are identical.)

Comment: In a metric space $d(a,b)=0$ implies $a=b$, so that if every point of one set is at zero distance from some point of the other one, then they must coincide. If instead $d(a,B)=0$ (distance from a *set*) then not necessarily there is a $b\in B$ which attains the infimum. The correct version is $\forall a\in A\forall \varepsilon>0\exists b\in B:d(a,b)<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more geometric interpretation, you can think of $D(A,B)$ as the infimum of the radii $r$ such that the $r$-neighbourhood of $A$ contains $B$ and at the same time the $r$-neighbourhood of $B$ contains $A$. The $r$-neighbourhood of a set $C$ is just the set of the points of the space whose distance from $C$ is less than $r$:
$$C_r:=\{x\in\mathcal{E}:d(x,C)< r\}.$$
This set looks like a fattened version of $C$, and can be obtained in this way: for every point $x\in C$ take the open ball of center $x$ and radius $r$, and take the union of all these balls. Indeed you can prove that
$$C_r=\bigcup_{x\in C} B(x,r).$$

As for the second question, if $d(A,B)=0$ then it is not true that the sets are equal, but they can not be very far from each other. In fact the following holds: the closure of one set contains the other set and viceversa (which implies that their closures coincide i.e. $\overline A=\overline B$). Indeed we must have
$$\sup_{a\in A} \inf_{\lower{0.5ex}{b \in B}} d(a,b)=\sup_{b \in B} \inf_{\lower{0.5ex}{a \in A}} d(a,b)=0$$
that is for every $a\in A$
$$\inf_{b\in B}d(a,b)=0$$
which implies that $a\in\overline B$, and for every $b\in B$
$$\inf_{a\in A}d(a,b)=0$$
which implies that $b\in\overline A$.
In particular, **if the two sets are closed**, then 
$$d(A,B)=0\iff A=B.$$